# Alias to search files by name and open them in vim

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, find, alias

I already have an alias to (more) quickly search files :

```
alias f='find . -iname'
```

I use it as such:

```
$ f *statis*
./main/statistics.py
./test/test_statistics.py
```

Now, I would like to have another alias that does the same search but, instead of printing out the found files, will open them in vim.
Ideally, it would work when multiple files are found.

I tried (using 'echo' instead of 'vim' for debugging purposes) :

```
 alias fvi='find . -exec echo {} + -iname'
```

...but it seems that `-exec` cancels the `-iname` coming afterwards:

```
$ fvi *statis*
 ./main/statistics.py ./main/probability.py ./test/test_statistics.py 
 ./test/test_probability.py
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the `-exec {}` arguments must come after the `-iname` (since `find` 'executes' its arguments from left to right), you can't do what you want using an alias. Instead let your alias invoke a script containing for instance:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -iname "$1" -exec vi {} \;
```

Note that this will invoke `vi` once for each file found. If there are many such files, you'll be doing many `:q!`'s or `ZZ`'s to get out of them. If you want to invoke one instance of `vi` to edit all files found, change the `\;` to a `+`:

```
find . -iname "$1" -exec vi {} +
```

Alternatively, you could use command substitution to provide the arguments to `vi`:

```
vi $(find . -iname "$1")   # do not use when file names may contain whitespace
```

However the downside to this is that it will fail on file names containing whitespace.

If you prefer not to create a script file for the command, instead put the statement in a shell function:

```
fvi () { find . -iname "$1" -exec vi {} + ; }
```

Comment: I was just about to post an answer very similar to this. The only difference
is that I was going to suggest implementing it as a shell function and I’d
terminate the `-exec` with `+` (like the OP) rather than `\;` to avoid
unnecessary process forks. That would result in only one instance of Vim being started.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan good point, and another alternative. Will add to answer.

Comment: Upvoted this already, however a little nitpickery about an edge case that is probably not even worth to be covered in the answer, but the second method will fail on filenames containing newlines; in case someone needs to avoid this they might use `find . -iname "$1" -print0 | xargs -0 -I file vi file` instead

Comment: Great answer, thanks. A shell function will do the trick fine.

Comment: The command substitution forms will break with filenames containing any whitespace - you shouldn't even suggest them.

Comment: @muru you are right. I have added a warning and changed the code in the function to use `find`. Have not followed kos's suggestion to use the `find -print0 / xargs -0` combo because this does not work well with vim. It gets confused about its `stdin` (that's a good one for a new question).

Answer (score 3):

### ... or use a dirty hack to use alias *as if* it took parameters ...

As several answers have pointed out, aliases do not support parameters the way shell scripts and functions do. Invoking an alias amounts to expanding the alias to its value, then executing the resulting command line with all arguments still in place.

No parameter substitution takes place. If you want parameter substitution, define a function instead of an alias. It's just as many keystrokes:

```
fvi () { find . -iname "$1" -exec vi {} + ; }
```

However, if you insist, here is a hack to refer to command line arguments inside an alias expansion: grab them from the shell history. In your case, this will do the job:

```
alias fvi='find . -iname "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e "s/^.*\sfvi\s*//")" -exec vi {} + #'
```

The output of the subshell executing `history | tail -n1 | sed -e "s/.*\sfvi\s*//"` is whatever follows `fvi`. This gets spliced into the `find . -iname HERE -exec vi {} +` command, which is what you need.

Except ... there is that queer hash sign at the end of the alias definition. I leave it to the reader to figure out its *raison d'être*, for the smile that unveiling a full-on hack brings. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need an alias, than you could use this answer.

---

An alias in the `bash` doesn't accept parameters. Therefore you need a function and an alias and a slightly changed `find` command:

1. Edit your `.bashrc`

   ```
   nano ~/.bashrc
   ```

   and add the lines below at the end of the file

   ```
   myfvi() {
       find . -type f -iname "$1" -exec vi -o {} +
   }
   alias fvi=myfvi
   ```
2. Reload the configuration or logout and re-login

   ```
   source ~./bashrc
   ```
3. Start with

   ```
   fvi '*statis*'
   ```

   But you could also use the function directly

   ```
   myfvi '*statis*'
   ```

---

*Example*

I have three files in my folder

```
$ ls -laog
total 4288
drwxrwxr-x  2 4329472 Sep  7 11:43 .
drwx------ 67   20480 Sep  7 11:28 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Sep  7 11:43 bar
-rw-rw-r--  1       4 Sep  7 11:23 foo
-rw-rw-r--  1       4 Sep  7 11:23 foobar
```

And when I use the alias

```
fvi 'foo*'
```

`vi` opens with two files.

[image]

Comment: I dont think alias even necessary. The user should be able to call function directly

Comment: @Serg Sure, but OP asked for an alias.

Comment: But then why not call the shell function `fvi`? I don't see the point.

Comment: @zwets No, but you have my +1 =)

Comment: That's what the OP asked for!  :D